# Разграничить элементы

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код по перетаскиванию элементов.

```js
/* определим тип браузера */
var bIE = 0;
bOp = 0;
bFF = 0;
var verBr = navigator.userAgent;
if (verBr.indexOf("Opera") != -1)
  bOp = 1;
else {
  if (verBr.indexOf("MSIE") != -1)
    bIE = 1;
  else {
    //if (verBr.indexOf("Firefox")!=-1)
    bFF = 1;
  }
}
setup_mouse("div_okno1", "zagol_okno1");
var obj_okno;
var obj_zagol_okno;
delta_x = 0;
delta_y = 0;

function setup_mouse(id_div_okno, id_div_zagol) {
  obj_okno = document.getElementById(id_div_okno);
  obj_zagol_okno = document.getElementById(id_div_zagol);
  obj_zagol_okno.onmousedown = save_delta_koor;
  if (bOp || bFF) {
    obj_zagol_okno.addEventListener("onmousedown", save_delta_koor, false);
  }
  document.onmouseup = clear_delta_koor;
}

function save_delta_koor(obj_evt) {
  if (obj_evt) {
    x = obj_evt.pageX;
    y = obj_evt.pageY;
  } else {
    x = window.event.clientX;
    y = window.event.clientY;
    if (bIE) {
      y -= 2;
      x -= 2;
    }
  }
  x_okno = obj_okno.offsetLeft;
  y_okno = obj_okno.offsetTop;
  delta_x = x_okno - x;
  delta_y = y_okno - y;
  document.onmousemove = motor_okno;
  if (bOp || bFF)
    document.addEventListener("onmousemove", motor_okno, false);
}

function clear_delta_koor() {
  document.onmousemove = null;
}

function motor_okno(obj_event) {
  if (obj_event) {
    x = obj_event.pageX;
    y = obj_event.pageY;
  } else {
    x = window.event.clientX;
    y = window.event.clientY;
    if (bIE) {
      y -= 2;
      x -= 2;
    }
  }
  new_x = delta_x + x;
  new_y = delta_y + y;
  obj_okno.style.top = new_y + "px";
  obj_okno.style.left = new_x + "px";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.div_okno {
  position: absolute;
}

.div_zagol_okno {
  cursor: move;
  background: url("./images/fon_left_zagol.gif") no-repeat;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #8CF4EF;
}

.div_zagol_okno div {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background: url("./images/fon_right_zagol.gif") right top no-repeat;
}

.div_zagol_okno div div {
  padding: 3px;
  background: #7c9992 url("./images/fon_zagol.gif");
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.content_okno {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #C0C0C0;
}

#div_okno1 {
  top: 120px;
  left: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_okno1" class="div_okno">
  <div id="zagol_okno1" class="div_zagol_okno">
    Элемент 1
  </div>
  <div id="zagol_okno1" class="div_zagol_okno">
    Элемент 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Но в этом коде можно переместить только элемент 1 элемент.
Как сделать что бы была возможность переносить элемент 2 без привязки к элементу 1?

Comment: У ваших элементов одинаковый id `id="zagol_okno1"`

Comment: Вы при движении мыши перемещаете контейнер, где находится элемент. Нужно же переносить сам элемент

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как переносить сам элемент.

Comment: В данном подходе не получится переносить элементы отдельно. У вас заданы глобальные переменные delta_x и delta_y. Какой элемент не двигайте - все равно изменяются эти переменные

Comment: Можете пожалуйста подсказать код по перенесу разных элементов?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(init);
function init(){
$("#myblock").draggable();
  $("#myblock2").draggable();
}
```

```css
#myblock
{
background-color: #0f7116;
width: 220px;
height: 170px;
color:#ffffff;
}
#myblock2
{
background-color: #0f7116;
width: 220px;
height: 170px;
color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Перетаскивание:</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body  >
    <div id="myblock">Перетащи меня</div>
    <div id="myblock2">Перетащи меня</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Сделал по другому. Вопрос закрыт.